# Removing "utf8=✓" from Rails 3 form submissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I have a simple search form in my Rails 3 app:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

When the user hits the submit button, they get taken to the URL: http://myapp.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=foobar
(where `%E2%9C%93` gets displayed as a checkmark: ✓).

I'm not doing anything with the `utf8` parameter, so I want to keep the URL clean by removing it entirely. That is, I want users to get taken to the URL: http://myapp.com/search?q=foobar instead.

How do I do this?

Comment: so what did you do eventually? just leave it there?

Comment: shingara's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104474/ works: just use `<form>...</form>` rather than `<%= form_tag %>...<% end %>`. Note that you should only do this if the submitted content can never end up in your database, as explained on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/ .

Comment: It is a very relevant question as I do not want to bother my users with workarounds for a single non-standards-complying browser. I only want this "utf8=✓" for the few IE users I have.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28201592/430695) re. the `:enforce_utf8` option for `form_tag`.

Comment: if you want to ignore the `utf8` param using Javascript/jQuery serialize, you can use the following: `$("form#my_form :input[name!='utf8']").serialize()`. It will ignore the `utf8` key/value pair in the serialized params

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Even though you aren't doing anything with the parameter, Rails is. It's to correct some issues in IE's parameter encoding. Yehuda has more info here:

[What is the _snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-rails-3-forms-for/3348524#3348524)

Comment: Is there a way to correct those issues in IE's parameter encoding by adding some default in my controller or whatnot instead?

Answer (score 41):

[`form_tag` in Rails 4.2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) (and probably earlier) has a `:enforce_utf8` option;

> If set to false, a hidden input with name utf8 is not output.

(Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201543/430695)

Answer (score 39):

Once you understand [the purpose of the Rails UTF-8 param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for/3348524#3348524), and for some reason you still need to remove it, the solution is easier than you think...just don't use the `form_tag` helper:

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get">
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
</form>
```

Comment: This helped me in configuring the submit_tag right, thank you!

Comment: But the `form_tag` helper brings several other features!

Answer (score 10):

There is gem ([utf8_enforcer_workaround](http://github.com/softace/utf8_enforcer_workaround)) for applying the utf8 param only for non standards complying browsers (or any other logic for that sake). This is handy if you don't want to bother your well behaving users with IE workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

I made an initializer to remove the param from GET requests. It's obviously a hack.

This goes in `config/initializers/overrides.rb`:

```
# Don't let Rails add a utf8=✓ param to GET forms.
# See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-rails-3-forms-for for details.
module ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
private

  def extra_tags_for_form_with_utf8_param_excluded_from_gets(html_options)
    old = extra_tags_for_form_without_utf8_param_excluded_from_gets(html_options)
    non_get = old.include?('"_method"') || old.include?('"'+request_forgery_protection_token.to_s+'"')
    if non_get
      old
    else
      old.sub(/<[^>]+name="utf8"[^>]+"&#x2713;"[^>]*>/, '').html_safe
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :extra_tags_for_form, :utf8_param_excluded_from_gets

end
```

Ideally, Rails should probably have a setting for this, or at least rewrite extra_tags_for_form so it's less messy to patch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your ApplicationController:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  options.delete('utf8')
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as that method must return a hash and may now return e.g. `nil`. But changing it to return something like `{ utf8: nil }` doesn't have the desired effect either.

Answer (score 1):

Using before_action and redirecting to another action worked for me.
For example, if you are searching for posts, set up a route for search on collection.

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

and make HTTP GET request for posts#index action.

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :q, params[:q], placeholder: "Search posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

and then in PostsController,

```
before_action :check_for_query, only: :index

    ... 


private 
  def check_for_query
    redirect_to articles_search_url(q: params[:q]) if params[:q].present?
  end
```

and call Post.search in posts#search action and render index page.

```
def search
   Post.search(params[:q])
   render :index
end
```

The URL will look like /posts/search?q=foo

Answer (score 1):

I think we should use: `enforce_utf8: false` in form_tag.

Ex:

```
= form_tag search_path, method: :get, id: 'searchForm', enforce_utf8: false
```