# Rewrite Rails response URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, actioncontroller

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102379/how-to-remove-blank-values-params-from-query-string).

I did `params.select!{|k, v| v.present?}` which cleans blank params, but I do not know how to make the response URL to be cleaned.

I continue getting something like `http://localhost:3000/restaurants/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&city=&cuisine=&number_of_people=&query=hello`

I am looking for `http://localhost:3000/restaurants/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=hello`

Also, I would delete utf8 param, is that bad?

## Update

I am considering a JavaScript solution, but I think this should be on the server:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // clean params, anyway is hard for me to figure this part out
  $(this).submit();
})
```

Comment: I think you have to redirect to the same URL, but with the filtered parameters. So probably check if filtering the parameters actually omits anything, and if it does, redirect to the same URL with the filtered parameters.

Comment: Are you redirecting the user? I don't understand where you want to rewrite the url.

Comment: I was thinking that redirecting is not what I want, I want to rewrite the response URL without  making a second request. Redirecting makes a second request, right?

Comment: all of this is for setting `link rel='next/prev'` for SEO, maybe I am complicating things, and I should just leave the the blank params, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to disable blank inputs and selects:

```
$('form').submit (e) ->
  $(@).find('select,input').map( (i, e) -> e.disabled = !$(e).val() )
```

Regarding removing `utf8` I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487796/1197775). So I better keep sending it.