# Rails form using GET request: How to remove button and utf8 params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just trying to create a simple select menu that takes you to a specific URL. So far I have something like this:

```
# haml
= form_tag new_something_path, method: :get do
  = select_tag :type, options_for_select(my_array)
  = submit_tag 'New Something'
```

However, when I submit the form I get the UTF8 parameter as well as a "commit" parameter with the text of the button.

How can I remove the UTF8 and commit parameters?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4488837/523568

Short answer: You shouldn't remove the UTF-8 parameter.

Also, you can't get rid of the commit parameter, given that part of the encapsulating form tag. You can change submit_tag's name with `submit_tag name: "whatever", "New Something"`

Comment: Yeah, I understand the purpose of the UTF-8 param, but in this case I don't need it because I know the form values will never include any special characters. So I would still like to know how to remove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "utf8=✓" from Rails 3 form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions)

Answer (score 45):

Removing the `commit` param is relatively simple, you need to specify that the input does not have a name:

```
submit_tag 'New Something', name: nil
```

Regarding the UTF-8 param...it serves an important purpose. Once you understand [the purpose of the Rails UTF-8 param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for/3348524#3348524), and for some reason you still need to remove it, the solution is easier than you think...just don't use the form_tag helper:

```
# haml
%form{action: new_something_path, method: 'get'}
  = select_tag :type, options_for_select(my_array)
  = submit_tag 'New Something', name: nil
```

Comment: In rails 4.1 introduced new option for form_tag – enforce_utf8. You can set it to false.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of the `utf8` param by adding the `enforce_utf8: false` option of `form_tag` (and also `form_form`) like the following:

```
= form_tag new_something_path, method: :get, enforce_utf8: false do
```

(thanks to @Dmitry for pointing that out)

But please make sure you don't need it: [What is the _snowman param in Ruby on Rails 3 forms for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222013/what-is-the-snowman-param-in-ruby-on-rails-3-forms-for/3348524#3348524) (I'm not sure if it is actually relevant for `GET` forms.)

The additional parameter is generated by the submit button can be removed by setting the `name: false` option on your `submit_tag` (Also works for `submit` in case of `form_for`).

```
= submit_tag 'New Something', name: nil
```