# My search is case sensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, utf-8

I am fairly new to rails, and am using this search form

```
  <%= form_tag producer_path(@user), method: :get do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

and in the model a SQL LIKE

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, conditions: ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

I expected this to be case insensitive by default, but it isn't. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1. Is this something I need to configure for the database, and if so where?

BTW I see the following paramaters in the URL including an UTF8 hash with an unprintable character (in the browser address bar, here in html it seems to show up as a check sign), which I don't know where that came for. Could this UTF8 encoding be the source of the problem?

```
?utf8=✓&search=
```

Comment: find(:all, conditions: ['lower(name) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%"])

Comment: in response to your second question, check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find(:all, conditions: ['name iLIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

Quoting from postgres docs:

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match
>   case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
>   SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: In the end I did, find(:all, conditions: ['LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?) ', "%#{search}%"])

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar thread,

[How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/case-insensitive-for-sql-like-wildcard-statement)

which is not really a rails solution. I would suggest you to try **meta-search** gem for searching which have sophisticated features.