# Unknown token in URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Whenever I submit a form rails append a unknown fragment in params in the url. But what is the purpose of that fragment ? and how I can get rid of it? Please refer to following sample URL.

By token I am referring to "#.U3Mw4XKHbFY" in the following URL

Here is URL sample

`www.domain.com/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=surf&area=All+Area#.U3Mw4XKHbFY`

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, method: 'get', class: "search_keywords_form" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, nil, class: "search-field", placeholder: "Search Item for swap" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'area', "All Area" %>  
  <input type="submit" class="search-btn" value="" />

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="push"></div>
<% end %>
```

Another strange thing is when I review the params, I don't get it there. But when page get reloaded That unknown attribute get appended.

```
params = { "utf8"=>"✓",
           "query"=>"surf",
           "area"=>"All Area",
           "action"=>"index",
           "controller"=>"posts"
         }
```

Comment: Can you add, in an edit to your question, the params hash that comes through (copied from your server log) as the result of submitting this form?

Comment: updated the question, thats the strange thing I don't get it in params.

Comment: Which token? Are you referring to the anchor?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions for the utf8 parameter

Comment: @mdesantis, by token i meant "#.U3Mw4XKHbFY" the last part in the url

Comment: @ArieShaw I already have mentioned i dont have any problem with utf-8

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say "fragment", not "anchor".

Comment: In your question, when you say `unknown "" params`, did you type something in the quotes which stackoverflow has removed?  (you get this writing certain things when you don't escape them with backticks)

Comment: Does the fragment identifier only appear after you submit the form?  Ie, when rails does the redirect after the form submission, it appears to be adding the fragment identifier?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: It might be from empty value in submit input. Try using rails `submit_tag` and see difference

Comment: Are you using google analytics, or another page tracking system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to face this problem, this is definitely JS problem might be some plugin would be appending this.

Simple solution for this is just put `location.hash = ""` in your js file on document ready. And yes i remembered, this fragment is appended when you use some tracking system. Like google analytics or [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/)

Comment: Thanks you are right fragment is appended because of AddThis

Answer (score 0):

What are you talking about is the [fragment part of an URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). The fragment part of the URI refers to some part of the HTML content response, and **it is processed only client side**: that's why you don't - and you can't - see or process it server side.

The fragment appears because it is present somewhere in the HTML form, or because some client side code (aka JavaScript) sets it to the form URL.

I have the feeling I have already seen that fragment pattern somewhere, but I don't remember where...

Comment: hmm, now you mention it, i think i've seen something like this too:  in pages that load different content with the same url (via ajax), there are javascript solutions for page tracking (eg for google analytics) which add fragment identifiers to the url as a way of recording activity.

Comment: Rather than comment out the JS, try switching off JS in your browser settings, going to the page from scratch and submitting the form again.

Comment: Also, search for that token inside the HTML page source

Comment: Thanks guys it was the issue because of AddThis