# How to remove “utf8=✓” when using form_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails automatically adds a UTF-8 parameter to forms when using `form_with`. How can you remove it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing "utf8=✓" from Rails 3 form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `:skip_enforcing_utf8` option to `true`. For example:

```
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: super_posts_path, skip_enforcing_utf8: true) %>
```

More information can be found [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

Answer (score 0):

In versions of Rails 4.1.8+ you can use:

`enforce_utf8: false`

See duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201592/514866