# Remove default 'GET' method parameters from URL

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the [generic search form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form), and my url after the search looks like

```
http://localhost:3000/search?commit=Search&page=2&query=feature&utf8=%E2%9C%93
```

The search works fine, but I would like to remove the default "utf8=✓" and "commit=Search" parameters from the URL, I'm also using `will_paginate` and I would like the `&page=2` to be after the query parameter leaving it like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?query=feature&page=2
```

My code:

```
#posts_controller.rb
def search 
    query = '%'+params[:query]+'%'        
    @posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["content LIKE ? or title LIKE ?", query, query]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

and

```
#html form
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => 'get') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag "query" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
#routes.rb
match '/search', :to => 'posts#search'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52196278/10275774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just remove it from url as far as YOU send it.

To clean up will_paginate try this

```
<%= will_paginate @whatever, params => params.merge({:commit => nil, :utf8 => nil}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does help with the pagination links, but it's still not perfect, and I can't decide the order of the params.

Comment: as far as `params` is a hash - so you cant sort it or order it (in Ruby 1.9+ you can). Hash is an unsorted list

Answer (score 4):

See similar questions:

[Rails 3 UTF-8 query string showing up in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104474/rails-3-utf-8-query-string-showing-up-in-url)

[removing "utf8=✓" from rails 3 form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions)

Basically, to remove 'commit=Search' add `:name => nil` to the submit_tag.  IE needs the utf8 character.  However, the second link has a initializer method to remove that part.

In this video, Ryan Bates talks about the `name: nil` fix (without ajax): http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates did a nice screen cast on exactly what you're trying to do (plus some more).

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: Thanks, I was able to remove the "commit=Search" but the utf8=✓ is still there, and I don't want to use AJAX for that. The utf8 param comes from a hidden div created by the form: `<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved utf problem by using

```
<form action="<%= root_path %>" method="get" >
...
</form>
```

instead of form_tag, it solved it.