# rails error in form because of utf8=✓ with meta search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, utf-8, meta-search

I have an issue in a search form with meta search :

When I submit my search form (method get) I have a 500 error because of the `utf8=✓` param added by rails.

`http://localhost:3000/items?utf8=✓&search[brand_contains]=levi`

If I delete the check mark (✓) in the url and press enter it works well.

I use rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.9.2.

I really don't know how to fix this issue so if you have any suggestion I will be happy to hear them.
Thank you for your help.

**Edit :**

Here is my form :

```
 = form_for @search, :class => "recherche" do |f|
  = f.label :brand
  = f.text_field :brand_contains
  = f.submit "Rechercher"
```

And the error :

```
Started GET "/items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search[brand_contains]=levi&commit=Rechercher" for 127.0.0.1  at 2011-09-02 17:39:39 +0200

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
```

Comment: I think this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104474/rails-3-utf-8-query-string-showing-up-in-url will help you with your problem :)

Comment: I understand why there is this parameter but I don't know how to fix my problem :(

Comment: Having the error (name, stack, etc) would be nice as well.

Comment: Having the stack would be even nicer ;-)

Comment: I have added another link to my answer. Maybe this one will be more helpful for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to implement something like this (following the lead from link from my comment):

```
<form action="<%= search_path %>" method="get" class="recherche" >
  <%= text_field_tag 'search[brand_contains]' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Rechercher", :name => nil %>
</form>
```

if this will not work then please look at this question: [removing "utf8=✓" from rails 3 form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions) This might be helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding the following line to environment.rb:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: @pefs commented "Where in environment.rb I need add [these lines]
First line, last line?"