# Rails 3, snowman and SEO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, search, optimization, seo

I'm wondering how the **[snowman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104474/rails-3-utf-8-query-string-showing-up-in-url)** affects the SEO.

For example, if someone puts a link to your post **with** the **snowman**, it means **two** URLs are pointing to the **same resource** (the other one without snowman), and basically this is **bad for search engines**.

Does this really poses a **problem**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about SEO you should already have 303 redirects for normalization in place, so that both the URL with and without *the snowmen* end up linking to the same URL, hopefully without any query parameter.

Also, this only affect forms that use the GET method; URLs that can only be retrieved via POST request are not crawled at all.

Minor note: the snowman is no longer used in current Rails versions, now you have `utf8=✓`.

Comment: Thanks! I mean, snowman or utf-8 and either for GET or POST, someone can put <a href="..."> by copying the URL from browser, and somehow this makes me think that it's still kind of bad.

Comment: This is why you have 303 redirects: so that people can only copy and paste GET-able URI without strange query details.