# can't get id with get request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I got a rails form:

```
<%= form_tag("/orders", action: "find",  method: "get") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:barcodeform) %>
        <%= submit_tag("find") %>
    <% end %>
```

this is my routes.rb

```
  post 'orders/uploadFile'
   resources :orders do
     member do
       get 'next_state'
     end

     member do
       get 'last_state'
     end

     member do
       get 'last_state_ablauf_2'
     end

     member do
       get 'log'
     end

     member do
       get 'save_Order'
     end

     member do
       get 'auftrag_annehmen'
     end

     member do
       get 'find'
     end
   end
```

controller:
Nothing special i just have set up a method called find in there is redirect to see if it works.

Now when I enter a value into the form it does this:

```
 http://example/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&barcodeform=631&commit=find
```

But i want it to do something like:

```
 http://example/orders/531
```

I don't get any search results, it just shows all entries. 
How should i do write the form to get this kind of result "/orders/id" ?
Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Could these be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions?rq=1  (or)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104474/rails-3-utf-8-query-string-showing-up-in-url?rq=1

Comment: The question is not about the utf8 stuff, It's about the logic behind my code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on, but first you should understand that the `utf8` information is generated by the Rails form helper [for a reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487796/removing-utf8-from-rails-3-form-submissions). If you really don't want it, build your own `<form>` instead of using the form helper.

Next, since the user is ostensibly supplying your `barcodeform`, it shouldn't be part of the form's action. You could accomplish something like that with a bit of javascript, but it wouldn't be best practice. You want that `barcodeform` value as a query parameter so you can access it in your controller with `params[:barcodeform]` and deal with whatever craziness your user inputs in an appropriate manner.

Lastly you need to fix your routes. Your routes are currently generating a url that looks like this:

```
http://example/orders/:id/find
```

Which, since you don't know the `:id` yet, you do not want. Instead, use `collection`:

```
collection do
  get 'find'
end
```

Now your form should look like:

```
<%= form_tag("/orders/find", method: "get") do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: hello, sry for my late response. thanks for your time and your help. you helped me out alot.